# Castle ControllerFactory Samples that don't work with MVC Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, castle-windsor

Following the samples that appear to be targeting MVC 3.0 and `Castle.Windsor` I've run into a bit of a snag - I know a workaround, but I am really confused about what the 'best practice' to do is now.

http://stw.castleproject.org/(S(su2mgm45fclhqe55veo40545))/Windsor.MainPage.ashx

In this example, the author constructs a `WindsorControllerFactory`. [ http://stw.castleproject.org/(S(su2mgm45fclhqe55veo40545))/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-part-two-plugging-Windsor-in.ashx ]

Here is the code he uses ...

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory: DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
    }

    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        var controllerComponentName = controllerName + "Controller";
        return kernel.Resolve<IController>(controllerComponentName);
    }
}
```

Now, this does work ...sort of. The problem comes with any `ASP.NET MVC` application that has **Areas** involved. The controllerName doesn't work there.

In other ControllerFactory implementations I have seen, people use the overrided method `GetControllerInstance` in a fashion like this ...

```
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
            throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found or it does not implement IController.", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));

        return (IController)_container.Resolve(controllerType);
    }
```

So I am confused. What is considered the best approach? `CreateController` or `GetControllerInstance`?

And before anyone brings up MVCContrib - I've explored it, and to be very frank, I must be either ridiculously stupid, or just missing the point, because I can't even find the ControllerFactory in it - and in the binaries I have downloaded for it, I couldn't get anything wired up. I understand this project is a very good one, not slamming it - but I see it referenced a lot and I can't find what people are talking about.

Can anyone help me clear up this mystery? Why did the author of this tutorial show us a ControllerFactory that won't work with Areas? How could it be made to work with them? Why do some use `CreateController` and some use `GetControllerInstance`? Any information is excessively appreciated.

Comment: IoC integration was removed from MvcContrib for ASP.NET MVC 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you're right. The existing implementation was OK in MVC 1 days before areas were introduced. Currently the `GetControllerInstance` method should be overriden to accommodate that. Feel free to fix it and submit a pull request.